# How to upload feedback from users in multiple languages?

Tags: android, http, utf-8, comments

I give my users of my Android-App the ability to respond there feedback to me.
Technically i just do a HTTP-Post to my PHP-Script that works as an connector to my DB where the feedback is stored.

Since my application is expanding around the globe, I'm getting confronted with the problems of multiple languages. I'm getting problems with this languages:

```
Espagnol - Espa&Atilde;&plusmn;a
Arabic - &Oslash;&sect;&Ugrave;„&Oslash;&
Korean - &euml;Œ€&iacute;•œ&euml;&macr;&f
Hungary - Magyarorsz&Atilde;&iexcl;g
Turkey - T&Atilde;&frac14;rkiye
Austria - &Atilde;–sterreich
```

What is the best-practice to implement a feedback-system that works everywhere around the globe?

Until now I did a AsyncTask that starts a HttpClient which powers a HttpPost. There is my Code:

```
public class reqeust_online extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>
        {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
            {
            }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
            int request_widget = 0;
            if(((CheckBox)request_dialog.findViewById(R.id.chx_request_widget)).isChecked())
                {
                request_widget = 1;
                }
            int request_gallery = 0;
            if(((CheckBox)request_dialog.findViewById(R.id.chx_request_gallery)).isChecked())
                {
                request_gallery = 1;
                }
            int request_sound = 0;
            if(((CheckBox)request_dialog.findViewById(R.id.chx_request_sound)).isChecked())
                {
                request_sound = 1;
                }
            /*  End */

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URI.create((getResources().getString(R.string.url_request_send))));
            try {
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request_widget", request_widget +""));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request_gallery", request_gallery +""));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request_sound", request_sound +""));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request_custom", ((EditText)request_dialog.findViewById(R.id.edt_request)).getText().toString()));
                // Debug information
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_country", Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry()));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_language", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_model", android.os.Build.MODEL));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_manufacturer", android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER));
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "UTF-8"));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                    {
                    return true;
                    }
                }
            catch (Exception e) {}
            return false;
            }
        }
```

and here is my PHP-Code that stores the values transmitted into my MysqlDB

```
connect_mysql();
$country = clean($_POST['device_country']);     
$language = clean($_POST['device_language']); 
$model  = clean($_POST['device_model']); 
$manufacturer = clean($_POST['device_manufacturer']);
$widget = clean($_POST['request_widget']);
$gallery = clean($_POST['request_gallery']);
$sound = clean($_POST['request_sound']);
$custom = clean($_POST['request_custom']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO wm2014_request (widget,gallery,sound,custom,country,language,model,manufacturer) VALUES ('$widget','$gallery','$sound','$custom','$country','$language','$model','$manufacturer')") or die (http_response_code(204));
http_response_code(200);

    function clean($str)
        {
        $str = @trim($str);
        $str = htmlentities($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
            }
        $str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
        $str = addslashes($str);
        return $str;
        }
```

I setup the MySQL DB with `utf8_general_ci` so this shouldn't be a problem.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
function clean($str)
{
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
```

Comment: I checked the input of the PHP-Script and the output of the clean() function and until there, everything is ok and trasmitted without problems. I can also insert the special characters directly via phpMyAdmin. Is there a problem with my mysql query?